# Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + .. + a_n x^{n}$. Assume $a_n \neq 0$ and n is odd. Prove $\exists$ x such that p(x)=0?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

I have no idea how to solve this question. I'm trying to show that given $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + .. + a_n x^{n}$ and further assuming that $a_n \neq 0$ and n is odd, there exists x such that p(x)=0.

I'm guessing that Rolle's theorem might come into play somewhere, since I know that by Rolle's theorem if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b) and f(a) = f(b) then $\exists c \in (ab)$ s.t f'(c)=0. Other than this hunch, I have no idea where to begin solving this.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here is another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498976/root-of-a-odd-degree-polynomial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use calculus rather than linear algebra, use the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).
Without loss of generality, assume $a_n=1$ (why is this allowed?). Then

$P(x)=x^n(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}+\frac{a_{n-2}}{x^2}+\cdots +\frac{a_{0}}{x^n})=x^n g(x)$ for $x\neq0$.
Notice how $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty} g(x)=1$ so for large enough $x$'s, $g(x)>0$ and hence $P$'s sign is determined by $x^n$ for large $x's$.

It follows there are $a<0,b>0$ such that $P(a)=a^n g(a)<0,\ P(b)=b^ng(b)>0$. Use $P$'s continuity to conclude there's a $c$ such that $P(c)=0$

This is the idea. If needed more elaboration don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I think the solution given by me is 'almost' same,its just that i have asked OP to fill the details!

Comment: It's not alike at all in my opinion! I didn't use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra or anything close to that.

Comment: @Theorem: I think Arpit Kansal was refering to his  solution1.

Comment: Sorry I did not see that as he edited that in after I started writing.

Comment: Dear @Theorem: No problem,i edited just because OP said he don't wanna use FTA!

Comment: Quick follow-up, the IVT listed in my book says given $x_1, x_2$, and if f is continuous and y lies between $f(x_1), f(x_2)$, then $\exists x \in x_1, x_2$ such that f(x)=y. In this case, our y is our 0, and $P(a) < 0$, and $P(b)>0$ gives us the fact that there exists a c between P(a) and P(b) such that f(c)=0? How do we find a<0  such that $P(a) = a^n g(a) <0$?

Comment: Using the limit definition, there is an $M$ such that for all $x>M$, $|g(x)-1|<1$, so $0<g(x)<2$ then if we take $b=|M|+1>M>0$ then $g(b)>0$ and hence $b^n g(b)>0$. Do the same for $a$.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some steps (without full details) which will lead you to the solution:

**Solution 1:** WLOG, assume $a_n>0$,now as $x \to \infty$ note that $p(x) \to \infty$ and as $x \to -\infty$ then $p(x) \to -\infty$.Now apply the IVP.

**Solution2:**

**Step 1:** Show that $P(\overline z)=\overline{P(z)}$,hence conclude that $z$ is a root of $p(z)$ iff $\overline z$ is a root of $p(z)$

**Step 2:** Recall Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

**Step:** Conclude that $p$ has at least one real root. **QED**

Comment: unfortunately I've not covered the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra in class. Apparently upon further probing, there was hint stating to use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Dear @Nikitau: i've added one more solution!

Comment: Thank you for the hint! :)